# Adding sources and javadoc of external library to eclipse / gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have an external library which is not in any maven repository, but is provided as a `jar` file. Therefore, I use the following line in the `build.gradle`:

```
compile files("/path/lib.jar")
```

I also have `lib-sources.jar` and `lib-javadoc.jar`, which I would like to include into the eclipse project as well, but using them as compile files in the same way as above does not work.

**Edit:**

For now, I use the approach by Creatorsuperman in combination with manual external source attachment as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8042592). Unfortunately, this does not work with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

> I also have lib-sources.jar and lib-javadoc.jar, which I would like to include into the eclipse project as well, but using them as compile files in the same way as above does not work.

Go to project > properties > Build Path > Libraries >Add External Library